# Translate CURL -form post request into Ktor

Tags: kotlin, curl, client, ktor

I am trying to translate a CURL POST request that uploads a XML file into Ktor.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/record/1/container/XML/' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <hidden>' \
--form 'upload=@"/data/1.XML”'
```

My current attempt:

```kotlin
val newRecordContainerURL = "https://example.com/record/1/container/XML/"
val newRecordContainerResponse = sessionsClient.post<NewRecordContainerResponse>(newRecordContainerURL) {
    header(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer ${session.token}")
    body = formData {
        appendInput("upload", Headers.Empty) { file.inputStream().asInput() }
    }
}
```

But when I try this, I get the following exception:

```
invalid: 400 Bad Request. Text: "{"messages":[{"message":"Request validation failed: Parameter (upload) is required","code":"10"}],"response":{}}"
```

Here are the full logs:

```
REQUEST: https://example.com/record/1/container/XML/
20:53:41.501 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
20:53:41.501 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - COMMON HEADERS
20:53:41.501 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Accept: application/json
20:53:41.501 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Accept-Charset: UTF-8
20:53:41.501 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Authorization: Bearer c2e3ee5082c3de555ef4b485b09cc6e024eb2a0851410e74def6
20:53:41.501 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - CONTENT HEADERS
20:53:41.501 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-2875dc98-223d0b421617663c-1c596ba4-3d5eecc280ab78e-552ff615-54c4764e1
20:53:41.501 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-2875dc98-223d0b421617663c-1c596ba4-3d5eecc280ab78e-552ff615-54c4764e1
20:53:41.516 [Ktor-client-apache] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY START
20:53:41.516 [Ktor-client-apache] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - ---2875dc98-223d0b421617663c-1c596ba4-3d5eecc280ab78e-552ff615-54c4764e1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=upload

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Cp1252" standalone="yes" ?>
<Test>
</Test>
---2875dc98-223d0b421617663c-1c596ba4-3d5eecc280ab78e-552ff615-54c4764e1--

20:53:41.516 [Ktor-client-apache] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY END
RESPONSE: 400 Bad Request
20:53:41.548 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - METHOD: HttpMethod(value=POST)
20:53:41.548 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - FROM: https://example.com/record/1/container/XML/
20:53:41.548 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - COMMON HEADERS
20:53:41.548 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Connection: close
20:53:41.548 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Content-Type: application/json
20:53:41.548 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Date: Sat, 10 Jul 2021 18:53:41 GMT
20:53:41.548 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Server: Apache
20:53:41.549 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
20:53:41.549 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
20:53:41.549 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> Vary: Accept-Encoding
20:53:41.549 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
20:53:41.549 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
20:53:41.549 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-1] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - -> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
20:53:41.549 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-3] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY Content-Type: application/json
20:53:41.549 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-3] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY START
20:53:41.550 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-3] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - {"messages":[{"message":"Request validation failed: Parameter (upload) is required","code":"10"}],"response":{}}
20:53:41.550 [ktor-apache-dispatcher-worker-3] INFO  io.ktor.client.HttpClient - BODY END
```

I am not sure what the `-form` part exactly does in curl. And how I can replicate this `upload` key in Ktor.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `filename` directive to solve your problem:

```kotlin
client.post<String>("https://example.com/record/1/container/XML/") {
    header("Authorization", "Bearer <hidden>")
    body = MultiPartFormDataContent(
        formData {
            append("upload", file.readBytes(), Headers.build {
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${file.name}")
            })
        }
    )
}
```